# Start theorem numbering after the last theorem in another document

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

I can reference theorems from another document using `xr` package.

Now I also want to start theorem numbering in the current document since the last theorem in the another document plus one.

Possible?

Comment: `\setcounter{theorem}{12}` in the preamble should make the first theorem 13. (It's possible to automate this but...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First document `portoncarryon.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\AtEndDocument{\refstepcounter{thm}\label{finalthm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
A
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
B
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

### Second document `portonget.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr,refcount}

\externaldocument[]{portoncarryon}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\setcounter{thm}{\getrefnumber{finalthm}}
\addtocounter{thm}{-1}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
C
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Comment

Are you sure you want to bother?