# Start figure numbering after the last figure in another document

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering

At [Start theorem numbering after the last theorem in another document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268137/18083) question I asked how to start theorem numbering after the last theorem in another document.

Now I ask how to do the same for figures: I want to start figure numbering after the last figure in another document. How?

I tried to replace `thm` with `figure` everywhere in [the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268140/18083) but this does not work.

---

Both documents are `amsbook` like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,english,reqno]{amsbook}
\begin{document}

...

\begin{figure}[ht]
\caption{\label{...}}
...
\end{figure}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a MWE that shows the documentclass and how the figures are numbered? Is the label of the last figure of the first document known?

Comment: @samcarter The label of the last figure of the first document is considered not known (I mean that it may change unexpectedly)

Comment: @samcarter an example added

Answer (score 2):

End the first document with

```
\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{LASTFIGURE}
\end{document}
```

Then use `xr` and `refcount` in the second document. Here's a full example.

### File `porton-first.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{B}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{C}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{D}
\end{figure}

Some text

\addtocounter{figure}{-1}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{LASTFIGURE}
\end{document}
```

### File `porton-second.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{refcount}

\externaldocument{porton-first}

\AtBeginDocument{\setcounter{figure}{\getrefnumber{LASTFIGURE}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{X}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Output of the second file

[image]

### *Caveat*

The second file should be compiled only if also the first file has and changes in labels are resolved.

Comment: I tried to add your code (with added `book-` prefix because `\externaldocument` argument) to my actual LaTeX sources (`volume-1.tex` and `addons.tex`). This does not work (the numbering starts from one). See https://github.com/vporton/algebraic-general-topology/tree/e98105c5ae71d4f45e4f6dc981e03b8645fd6ebd for the exact sources.

Comment: @porton No, I won't go through a complex tree of documents. Of course, if figures are numbered by chapter, the concept of “restarting the figure number” doesn't make sense. I guess it's a problem of using `\include`, anyway.

Comment: Figures are not numbered by chapter

Comment: The weird thing is that it does work for theorem numbers but does not for figure numbers